# Creating SvelteKit library with reusable routes

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'd like to create a SvelteKit library that provides a list of routes that the library user can then add to their Svelte app tree. This would be similar to some web frameworks, like [reusable apps in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/reusable-apps/).

- Is creating reusable routes in the library currently possible with SvelteKit?
- If it is possible are there any libraries that could be good examples to look upon?
- If this is not possible then what's the next best alternative to provide easy route integrations to library users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is creating reusable routes in the library currently possible with SvelteKit?
> If you want something like django then no, it's not possible.

Because of the file system based nature of SvelteKit's routing you can't define "routes" from outside of `config.kit.files.routes`.

However, you can define the response of those routes from anywhere. For endpoints, this is as simple as reexporting the `RequestHandler` functions with the proper name from your package.

For pages it's a bit more involved, for the script part it's again as easy as just reexporting. For the markup, it'd mean doing something like:

```html
<script context="module">
    export * from "your-lib/your-page.svelte";
    import YourPage from "your-lib/your-page.svelte";
</script>

<YourPage />
```

Comment: Nice! Does the exported page include `load()` handling and so on, or does this need to be somehow exported separately?

Comment: `export * from "your-lib/your-page.svelte";` would mean `your-page.svelte`'s load function (if it exports one) gets treated as the load function for whichever page has that export statement. I hope that answers your question.